# IBM Informix Server - List users with DBSECADM role

Tags: sql, identity, roles, informix

After granting user DBSECADM role, there are no results from any of these queries:

- `SELECT * FROM sysroleauth`
- `SELECT * FROM syssurrogates`
- `SELECT * FROM sysusers`

How to get the list of users with Database Security Administrator (DBSECADM) role?

Are built-in roles and role members stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

- `SELECT * FROM sysdbsecadmauth`

The table `sysdbsecadmauth` from the `sysuser` database list all users with DBSECADM role.